# Dygraph outputs different date intervals for x-axis in viewer when compared to html

Tags: r, dygraphs

When I load the dygraph of the below code, the viewer presents it like this:

[image]

but when loaded into my dashboard in html it converts to this:

[image]

How do I stop it changing the date intervals and keep it in the first format?

```
f <- data.frame(data1$exchange_feeGBP, data1$submitted_at)
f$data1.submitted_at<- as.POSIXct(f$data1.submitted_at, tz="UTC", format = "%Y %m %d")
f <- xts(f[,-2], order.by=f[,2])
f <- apply.daily(f, sum)
names(f) <-"Revenue"
f <- na.omit(f)
f$Revenue <- cumsum(f)
dygraph(f) %>%
  dyAxis( "y",
          drawGrid = T,
          gridLineColor = "#cccccc",
          axisLabelFormatter = 'function(y){return "£" + y.toString()}') %>%
  dyOptions(fillGraph=T, colors = "#e93cac", drawGrid = F, gridLineColor = "grey") %>%
  dyCrosshair(direction="vertical")
```